# How to use tangent maps in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-algebras

In my lectures the following was said:
[image]

But I have no idea how to take the tangent map of (3.19) to get that expression. More generally, I realized I don't know how to take tangent maps in complicated scenarios and examples/explanations would be very helpful!

Edit:

I know that $T_e(T_eF\circ Ad)=T_{Ad(e)}T_eF \circ T_e Ad=T_eF\circ ad$ but when I attempt this with the RHS $T_e(Ad(F)\circ T_eF)=T_{F(e)}(Ad\circ F) T_e T_eF$ clearly doesn't work (the $T$ aren't even acting on the right things) but I have no idea what to do instead.

Comment: Chain rule and definition of ad.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was wondering how you would do it for the RHS, I did manage to figure out how to do the LHS.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include details and show exactly where you're stuck? To me it just looks like chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have updated the question. (And thank you!)

Comment: I don't know what $T_{\text{Ad}(e)}$ means. And why did you drop the $g$ in $\text{Ad}(g)$? Keep track of where everything lives. $T_e(F)\colon T_eG\to T_{\tilde e}\tilde G$, and $\text{Ad}(F(g))\colon T_{\tilde e}\tilde G\to T_{\tilde e}\tilde G$.